# How to use visitor locale in middleman?

Tags: middleman

How can you serve your middleman site in the HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE locale? For instance, let's say the HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE is "FR", and that `mount_as_root: :en` is specified, do I have to redirect the user to `/fr` with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

As middleman produces just plain HTML and there is no server language (like PHP, Ruby) involved, JavaScript might be a choice, but probably not the best.
Your webserver can also do that for you, for some Apache examples see http://www.htaccesstools.com/redirection-by-language/ or http://tech-blog.borychowski.com/index.php/2009/03/htaccess/redirect-according-to-browser-language-mod-rewrite-and-http_accept_language/.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (fr) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /fr [L]
```